# How can I specify build pragmas in index.html?

Tags: html, node.js, build, pragma

I have an index.html file.  I want to specify build pragmas in this file, so I can include my dev stuff when developing and specify production at build time.

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


//>>excludeStart("devEntry", pragmas.build);
    <script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="scripts/baseRequireConfig.js"></script>
//>>excludeEnd("devEntry", pragmas.build);

//>>excludeStart("prodEntry", pragmas.build);
<!--
//>>excludeEnd("prodEntry", pragmas.build);
<script src="require.js" data-main="productionRequireConfig.js"></script>
//>>excludeStart("prodEntry", pragmas.build);
-->
//>>excludeEnd("prodEntry", pragmas.build);

</body>
</html>
```

Only using HTML pragmas rather than r.js ones.  What are some options for this?  node.js plugin?  Some bash thing?  `make`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `sed` to change the text

```
cat index.html |\
    sed s,bower_components/requirejs/require.js,require.js,g |\
    sed s,scripts/baseRequireConfig.js,productionRequireConfig.js,g \
    > build/index.html
```

Works for my current scale, but I wouldn't push it too far.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess), which offers the equivalent `@exclude`/`@excludeend` declarations, e.g.:

```html
<!-- @exclude -->
<script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="scripts/baseRequireConfig.js"></script>
<!-- @endexclude -->
```